# Hector get all columns

Tags: hector

I am trying to use the following code but it's says invalid constructor `ColumnSliceIterator`

```
SliceQuery<String, UUID, String> query = HFactory
                .createSliceQuery(keyspaceOperator, StringSerializer.get(),
                        UUIDSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get())
                .setKey(login).setColumnFamily(FRIENDS_CF);

        ColumnSliceIterator<String , UUID, String> iterator = new ColumnSliceIterator<String, UUID, String>(query, null, "\uFFFF", false);
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SliceQuery<String, UUID, String> query = HFactory
                .createSliceQuery(keyspaceOperator, StringSerializer.get(),
                        UUIDSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get())
                .setKey(login).setColumnFamily(FRIENDS_CF);
        ColumnSliceIterator.ColumnSliceFinish<UUID> FINISH = new ColumnSliceIterator.ColumnSliceFinish<UUID>() {
            @Override
            public UUID function() {
                return TimeUUIDUtils.getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis();
            }
        };
        ColumnSliceIterator<String, UUID, String> iterator = new ColumnSliceIterator<String, UUID, String>(query, null, FINISH, false, 100);
        List<String> friendIds = new LinkedList<String>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            friendIds.add(iterator.next().getName().toString());
        }
        return friendIds;
```